# How to pass a property from an ASP.Net page to a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, user-controls

I have created a user control which exposes a custom type property called SoftwareItem. The page where I have placed this user control has a page property of the same type. I cannot figure out how to pass the page's property to the user control. I understand that this can be done in the code_behind but wanted to set the property declaratively  to avoid view state issues with setting this property in the code behind.

Comment: Do you want to set SoftwareItem property of user control from your ASP .Net page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code behind for the user control, do you have the property defined as the custom type?

As in:

```
public MyCustomType SoftwareItem {get; set;}
```

Comment: If your MyProperty variable isn't a standard int/string/etc. you may need to do the actual setting in your code behind file on page load as opposed to doing it "inline."

Comment: @Dillie-O If you can't do it inline how would someone *easily* maintain view_state?